# Hibernate JPA composite key with @ManyToOne BUG?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this 2 tables (master and detail, note the second table has a composite key)

```
CREATE TABLE MESTRE (
    ID         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DESCRICAO  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE MESTRE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MESTRE PRIMARY KEY (ID);

CREATE TABLE DETALHE (
    MESTRE_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ID         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DESCRICAO  VARCHAR(50)
);
ALTER TABLE DETALHE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_DETAHLE PRIMARY KEY (MESTRE_ID, ID);
ALTER TABLE DETALHE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DETAHLE_1 FOREIGN KEY (MESTRE_ID) REFERENCES MESTRE (ID);
```

For this 2 tables I have this JPA mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESTRE")
public class Mestre {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "COD_PVEITE", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "COD_PVEITE", sequenceName = "COD_PVEITE", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "DESCRICAO")
    private String descricao;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mestre", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Detalhe> detalhes = new ArrayList<Detalhe>(0);

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public List<Detalhe> getDetalhes() {
        return detalhes;
    }

    public void setDetalhes(List<Detalhe> detalhes) {
        this.detalhes = detalhes;
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "DETALHE")
@IdClass(Detalhe.PK.class)
public class Detalhe {

    public static class PK implements Serializable {

        private Integer metreId;
        private Integer id;

        public PK() {
        }

        public PK(Integer metreId, Integer id) {
            this.metreId = metreId;
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Integer getMetreId() {
            return metreId;
        }

        public void setMetreId(Integer metreId) {
            this.metreId = metreId;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((metreId == null) ? 0 : metreId.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            PK other = (PK) obj;
            if (id == null) {
                if (other.id != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                return false;
            if (metreId == null) {
                if (other.metreId != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!metreId.equals(other.metreId))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MESTRE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer metreId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "COD_PVEITE", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "COD_PVEITE", sequenceName = "COD_PVEITE", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MESTRE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Mestre mestre;

    @Column(name = "DESCRICAO")
    private String descricao;

    public Integer getMetreId() {
        return metreId;
    }

    public void setMetreId(Integer metreId) {
        this.metreId = metreId;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Mestre getMestre() {
        return mestre;
    }

    public void setMestre(Mestre mestre) {
        this.mestre = mestre;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

}
```

When I query over this entities, there is no problems:

```
Mestre mestre = entityManager.find(Mestre.class, 1);
for (Detalhe detalhe : mestre.getDetalhes() {
     // do the stuff
}
```

But when I try to persist a new Mestre an exception occours.

```
Detalhe d = new Detalhe();
Mestre m = new Mestre();
m.setDescricao("mestre");

d.setMestre(m);
d.setDescricao("detalhe");

m.getDetalhes().add(d);

em.persist(m);
```

The stack trace:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not insert: [br.com.jjw.besser.core.model.Detalhe]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [br.com.jjw.besser.core.model.Detalhe]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:310)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at br.com.jjw.besser.core.controller.MestreDetalheRestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef43eafc.create(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [br.com.jjw.besser.core.model.Detalhe]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3144)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: Invalid column index.
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.getField(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:520)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.setNull(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:234)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setNull(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:407)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrateId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2880)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2849)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3121)
    ... 94 more
```

Comment: Detalhe.id is autogenerated by a sequence. So it's guaranteed to be unique. So it should be the primary key of the table, and the ID of the entity. No need to include MESTRE_ID in the primary key, nor in the entity ID.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry man, this isn't an option. This is a olddatabase (ERM), the primary key must be preserved for performance